# Converse of intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

By IVT, we have $f(a,b)$ is always an interval (maybe not open).

We have also conter-examples to show that sometimes there exists $(c,d)\subset f(\mathbb{R})$, but no interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(a,b)=(c,d)$. But could we find a necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to satisty this property?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's a counter-example when $f$ is continuous but no such interval exists?

Comment: $f(x) = xsin(x)$, $[0, +\infty)$

Comment: Using $+\infty$ is a bit of a different case. I had trouble coming up with an example where $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$; do you know if any examples like that exist? If it's only infinity that causes problems, that's different.

Comment: @Misha We could try to make f tender to 1 at infinity but never attain

Comment: Certainly if we can say that $f$ attains the values $c$ and $d$ finitely many times (or at least that $f^{-1}(\{c,d\})$ has no accumulation points) then the converse holds. But that's too strong a condition.